# Understand what ee.data.getTaskStatus returns

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, documentation, tasks

This is maybe very simple question but I could not find the documentation for this function :
"ee.data.getTaskStatus" . I could only get the ["ee.data.getTaskStatus"](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-updatetask) documentation page.
My question is, what exactly each parameter in the dictionary means? I can assume but I would like to be sure about it:

```
ee.data.getTaskStatus("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP26QRSTUB")

[{'state': 'COMPLETED',
  'description': 'task',
  'creation_timestamp_ms': 1695901638238,
  'update_timestamp_ms': 1695901780869,
  'start_timestamp_ms': 1695901650193,
  'task_type': 'EXPORT_IMAGE',
  'destination_uris': ['https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/my_secret_bucket/path/to/secrets'],
  'attempt': 1,
  'batch_eecu_usage_seconds': 234.16341019503,
  'id': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP26QRSTUB',
  'name': 'projects/earthengine-legacy/operations/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP26QRSTUB'}]
```

**I want mainly to understand the timestamp keys. My end goal is to be able to understand how long did it take for the task to run, since it started until it was uploaded.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you are looking for is here:

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-getoperation

```
+ state: PENDING, RUNNING, CANCELLING, SUCCEEDED, CANCELLED, or FAILED

+ description: Supplied task description

+ type: EXPORT_IMAGE, EXPORT_FEATURES, etc.

+ create_time: Time the operation was first submitted.

+ update_time: Timestamp of most recent update.

+ start_time: Time the operation started, when so.

+ end_time: Time the operation finished running, when so.

+ attempt: Number of retries of this task, starting at 1.

+ destination_uris: Resources output by this operation.

+ batch_eecu_usage_seconds: CPU used by this operation.
```

However, there seems to be some small differences in the structure of the response, e.g. `creation_timestamp_ms` instead of `create_time`, which is returned in human-readable format. Also, the way you use `ee.data.getOperation` is with the standard ["long running operations"](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/design_patterns#long_running_operations) name, i.e. `projects/project-name/operations/taskid` where `taskid` is the `id` that you used for `ee.data.getTaskStatus`.

I think the `ee.data.getOperation` is the recommended one to use now instead of `ee.data.getTaskStatus` (which is no longer listed in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs)).

Comment: thank you for the answer! there is something I don't understand, what should be inside the function? adduming I have my task id as str, but seems like it expect other type (TypeError: Parameter "name" value "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP26QRSTUB" does not match the pattern "^projects/[^/]+/operations/.*$"

Comment: "projects/project-name/operations/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP26QRSTUB"